# не работает код на js

Tags: javascript

не может определить id, использовал сначала вместо

```
var select = $(this); var id = select.attr('href');
```

```
var id = $(this).attr('href');
```

не помогло, `console.log($(id));` тут только для проверки

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
    event.preventDefault();

    //забираем идентификатор блока с атрибута href
    var select = $(this);
    var id = select.attr('href');

    console.log($(id));

    //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
    var top = $(id).offset().top;

    //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="footer" id="footer">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ex1">Вверх</a></li>
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>
    </ul>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: не может определить id, использовал сначала вместо "var select = $(this);
    var id = select.attr('href'); "  "var id  = $(this).attr('href');", не помогло,  console.log($(id)); тут только для проверки

Comment: приведенный код работает именно так как ожидается - берет href и переходит к соответствующему элементу. Если не переходит, значит на странице нет элемента с указанным `id`